# javac/java commands yields different default time zones depending on invoking shell

Tags: java, windows, timezone

This question is not about how to set the timezone, but how the default time zone can differ depending on the shell from which `java`/`javac` is invoked.  The default time zone is UTC when the commands are issued from Cygwin's Bash and Eastern Time when issued from CMD.  These are easily corrected through explicit specification of the time zone, but it is a mystery to me why the default differs.

- Both `java` and `javac` are issued on the same Windows laptop and same login session, and full paths are consistent, as are the arguments to for both commands, e.g., specifying paths for jar files and such
- This suggests that the discrepancy between default time zones is related to the shell environments rather than Windows settings, yet the only such information I can find is the `TZ` environment variable.
- `TZ` is empty when queried from CMD, but properly set to [`America/Toronto`](https://garygregory.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/what-are-the-java-timezone-ids) from Bash, i.e., Eastern Time.  Therefore, I should expect `java` invocation from Bash to be more likely to have the correct default time zone compared to invocation from CMD, but I observe the opposite.

What factors could lead to discrepant *default* time zones, pertaining to the shell environments rather than Windows itself (or the JDK)?

Comment: I would guess that Java uses the time zone of the system - Windows settings for CMD (`TZ` is hardly used for this); Cygwin's settings for the corresponding shell (I get the same zone using CMD or GIT-Bash -- no idea how `javac` is supposed to be affected by the time zone).

Comment: I agree that it makes sense for Java to simply look up OS's time zone, which is set to Eastern Time.  The invocation from CMD shows the proper local time, despite the absence of `TZ`.  `TZ` is properly set in Bash, which invokes exactly the same executables with the same arguments, so the only factor might disrupt the inheritting of the time zone from the OS is not an explanation in this case.  Baffling.